# Pagination and searchbox not display in bootstarp datatable when data fill using ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

When i display data in bootstrap datatable using ajax jquery then pagination and search box is not display.so how to solve this problem

My html sample code is here.

```
 <div class="row" style="margin-top: 2em;">
     <div class="panel panel-white">
       <div class="panel-heading clearfix">

       </div>
       <div class="panel-body">
           <div id="live_data" >
             //data table display here                         
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

And my ajax file code is here

```
    <?php

    $output='';     
    $output.='  <div class="table-responsive">
                   <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-
                     bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>                                                        
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>';
echo $output;
?>
```

And my jquery function is here

```
 getcamera();
        function getcamera(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:'../ajaxfiles/ajax_getcamera.php',
                success:function(data){
                    $('#live_data').html(data);

                }
            });
        }


This above code is work properly but search box and pagination is not display
```

so how to solve that problem???

Answer (score 0):

```
 `getcamera();
    function getcamera(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:'../ajaxfiles/ajax_getcamera.php',
            success:function(data){
                $('#live_data').html(data);
                 $('#example').DataTable();// Add this line.
            }
        });
    }`
```

Above code will work. This is not the best solution.
For good ajax implementation you can see example usages at
 https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html And https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

Comment: $('#live_data').DataTable();// Add this line

Comment: are you using datatables.net.

Comment: please make sure your table paging, searching works with static html.

Comment: $('#example').DataTable();// Add this line.

Comment: thank you so much  $('#example').DataTable() line is work for me